# Vlookup, For Next, with tree variables

Tags: vba, for-loop, variables, vlookup

I spent hours trying to make my code working without any success.

I am trying to sum the vlookup results in function of two conditions.

If the input value by the user in any level is more than 0 and different than "" vlookup at the input value which would correspond to the pipe number and sum of all the vlookup value.

Basically, the objective of the exercise is to enter the pipe number which is/are before and to sum the associated pressure in colum EY. Therefore I would be able to know what is the most defavorised pipe in my network to design my pump.

I guess this is not very clear but please find below the link of my file which might help you to understand.

Do not hesitate to ask for any clarification.

Many thanks for any help thta you could provide me with.

Have a nice day

Here is a link to download the file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcfw9ybeds082qa/Help.xlsx?dl=0

```
Sub test()
Dim y As Integer, total As Integer
total = 0
For y = 3 To 152
If Not Cells(8, y).Value = 0 And Cells(8, y).Value = "" Then
total = total + cells(8,"EY").value + Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(8, y).Value, Sheets("Pump Design").Range("Pump_design"), 154, False)
y = y + 1
End If
Next y

Cells(8, "EZ").Value = total

End Sub
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the formula you're using. That way we can copy it to test it, and people can easily see it without downloading a file they may not trust.

Also, it makes a better question if you narrow it down to a specific problem like "my VLOOKUP is returning #VALUE" or "How do I select the cell before and after a cell and sum them?"

Comment: @Noumenon done see code in my question

Comment: Which column is supposed to hold the "associated pressure"? No column is labeled "pressure".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why, but your conditional is never true. If you replace

```
If Not Cells(8, y).Value = 0 And Cells(8, y).Value = "" Then
```

with

```
If Not (Cells(8, y).Value = 0 Or Cells(8, y).Value = "") Then
```

or

```
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(8, y)) Then
```

then it should work.

Comment: Ok thanks for this but my vlookup function does not work either. If I replace :                                                                                                          `total = total + Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(8, y).Value, Sheets("Pump Design").Range("Pump_design"), 154, False)`                                       with `total = total + Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(8, 4).Value, Sheets("Pump Design").Range("Pump_design"), 154, False)` it works.... why???

Comment: @MAxSegura Which cells does `Range("Pump_design")` refer to? I don't see it in the Named Ranges menu.

Comment: I fixed the problem, in the file range("Pump_design") is the name of the entire table. The main issue was x and y not being declared as double and also for y = 3 to 153 replaced by y= 4 to 153.

Comment: Now I am trying to replicate the macro for each line, so I will spend some time on it as I do not have any idea on how :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
Sub test()
Dim total As Integer, x, y  As Double
For y = 4 To 153
x = Cells(8, y).Value
If Not IsEmpty(x) Then
total = total + Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Sheets("Pump Design").Range("Pump_design"), 154, False)
End If
Next y

Cells(8, "EZ") = total
End Sub
```

However, I still need to make some changes to get to the result that I want